# Cakephp 3.3 sorting pagination results by multiple columns

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination

Need some help in sorting paginated result in cakephp 3.3
I want to sort by multiple columns but pagination consider only the first if I go on next (or any other page).
Is it a feature or a bug?

This is the pagination command in controller:

```
$this->paginate = [
            'limit' => 20,
            'order' => [
                'Iktato.evszam' => 'DESC',
                'Iktato.iktatoszam' => 'DESC'
                ]
        ];
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT 
  Iktato.id AS `Iktato__id`, 
  Iktato.iktatoszam AS `Iktato__iktatoszam`, 
  Iktato.evszam AS `Iktato__evszam`, 
  Iktato.datum AS `Iktato__datum`, 
  Iktato.honnan AS `Iktato__honnan`, 
  Iktato.felado AS `Iktato__felado`, 
  Iktato.cimzett AS `Iktato__cimzett`, 
  Iktato.targy AS `Iktato__targy`, 
  Iktato.tema AS `Iktato__tema`, 
  Iktato.iktatoszemely AS `Iktato__iktatoszemely`, 
  Iktato.megjegyzes AS `Iktato__megjegyzes`, 
  Iktato.allapot AS `Iktato__allapot`, 
  Iktato.user_id AS `Iktato__user_id` 
FROM 
  iktato Iktato 
ORDER BY 
  Iktato.evszam desc 
LIMIT 
  20 OFFSET 20
```

The generated pagination links has only one sorting parameter. How can we force Paginator helper to consider the second parameter too?

Comment: A mezőnevekből úgy tűnik, hogy magyar vagy :) Van egy CakePHP-s facebook csoportunk ha érdekel https://www.facebook.com/groups/cakehu/

Comment: Köszi! Jövök máris!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a custom finder. In your model's table class:

```
public function findOrdered(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->order([
            'Iktato.evszam' => 'DESC',
            'Iktato.iktatoszam' => 'DESC'
        ]);
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'limit' => 20,
    'finder' => 'ordered',
];
```

With this the pagination links should work as expected, though if you are using pagination column sorting (`$this->Paginator->sort('evszam')`, etc.) in your view you'll still have issues.